# Problem with apache2 with ProxyPass (serviio)

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy, webserver

I have this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   proxypass / http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/
   proxypassreverse / http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/

   proxypassmatch "/(.*)" http://127.0.0.1:23423/$1
   proxypassreverse "/(.*)" http://127.0.0.1:23423/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when i type "mydomain.com", I want it to open the "console" page (it would be the index). The problem is that the other configuration files are not located on the `/console` path, but on `/`. So, it is possible to set that when opening the site (therefore without arguments-path) open console, but if there is a specific request, go to `/`? I have set **proxypassmatch** but it doesn't seem to work ... why?

Answer (score 1):

Your first `ProxyPass` gets all requests and there are no requests left for the `ProxyPassMatch`. 
Change it to use the `ProxyPassMatch` only for `/`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # special treatment for /
    ProxyPassMatch   ^/$ http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/

    ProxyPass         /  http://127.0.0.1:23423/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://127.0.0.1:23423/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I just tried but unfortunately not completed ... I get an XML error: ```The specified XML file apparently does not have an associated style sheet. The document tree is shown below.```

Comment: Your error or served XML document is not related to the `ProxyPass` settings. You should check your backend on `http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/` or whatever the URL was.

Comment: The problem is the path 'assets'. In fact I tried to set these other lines but it doesn't work ... the regular expression doesn't work. Why? ```ProxyPassMatch ^/assets(.*) http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/assets/$1``` and ```ProxyPassReverse /assets http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/assets```

Comment: Also, if I try to remove the ```/``` at the end of ```http://127.0.0.1:23423/console/```, the xml error no longer appears, but the page does not load and remains white ... why? Here is the error reported (seen by chrome): ```Loading failed for <script> with source "https://mydomain.io/assets/js/app.min.js```

Comment: If you want to serve everything after `/assets` or `/assets/` from the proxy, you can use a `ProxyPass` with `ProxyPassReverse`. Please ask a new question and provide better examples how your path mapping looks like. I don't know what `https://mydomain.io` is (frontend, backend?) and where the resources are.

Comment: You are right. I explain better.
   2 I have a service locally (serviio) where I have configured (not only this service) many    services with https (via proxypass). Now I'm trying to do the same thing even with servant    (but as we understand it ... without success).

Comment: mydomain is my personal domain that I created with bind9 (which would be my server 192.1   68.2.1).

Comment: Now, I'm looking through apache2 (with https) to "convey" the requests on the ser   ver locally ... but I'm having many problems.

Comment: the only thing I can tell you (from what i understood by reading the various requests) is that **index.html** is found in ```/console```, **asssets** in ```/console/assets``` and **rest** in ```/rest```. So we have this structure locally: ```192.168.2.1:23423/console```, ```192.168.2.1:23423   /console/assets/...ecc.``` and ```192.168.2.1:23423/rest/....ecc.```, while from the outside the requests look like this: ```mydomain.io/console```, ```mydomain.io/console/assets/.   ..ecc.``` and ```mydomain.io/rest/....ecc.```

Comment: I solved it like this: **https://pastebin.com/JmTFcG0X**. It's correct? I haven't added the ```proxypassreverse``` directive ... does anything change?

Comment: If it works, then it works. I can't test this since I don't have your setup. I think that the lines with `/mediabrowser` and `^/(cds.*)` (this one is duplicated) can be removed, but again, I can't test this. You need [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) 
to rewrite the location headers on redirects and this can be difficult to impossible for `ProxyPassMatch` matches.

Comment: So I leave it then ... so much, as far as I understand, this directive (in this case) is not needed, right? (since the page does not redirect anything) _**NB**. the proxymatch directives are not the same as they point to the same ip, but to different ports_